# Adding elements to lists inside of nested dictionary Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

For an assignment, I want to add a list inside of a nested dictionary like this.

```
{Num:{Name: John, Grades:[1,2,3,4]}}
```

where Num, Name, and Grades are acquired from the user. I got it to work when there is only one user using .update, but when I have two or more users, it does not work and instead, it gives me something like this.

```
{Num1:{}, Num2: {Name: John, Grade:[]}}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you give us an example of how you are using this?

Comment: its a assignment grader. I want to get user's name, their ID number as user input. Then User is asked if they have another user to add, if answered yes, user can add another user. If answered no, user is asked how many assignments they have. and then user can enter their scores on each assignments.

Answer (score 0):

I kind of think you might consider using `list` for storing different users.

```py
users = []
while True:
    more_user_query = input("will there be more users? [y]|n  ")
    if more_user_query == 'n':
        break
    # I think you should have get some code to get the user info
    user_info = get_uesr_info()
    users.append(user_info)
```